# Do Blast Boots ignore your Speed?

Tags: magic-items, movement, pathfinder-2e

[Moderate Blast Boots](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1104) increase your Long Jump distance:

> When you Activate them to Long Jump, you can **increase** the horizontal distance of your **Long Jump by up to 45 feet**.

Anyone can [Leap](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=81) 10 feet, and if you base speed is at least 30 feet, you can Leap 15. Increasing this **by** (not to) 45 feet is more than than most non-Monk characters have as speed.

However, [Long Jump](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=37) says:

> You can’t Leap farther than your Speed.

If this is also valid for Blast Boots, basically for everyone beside 19th level Elven Monks with Fleet, this just means "Jump up to your Speed".

**Do Blast Boots ignore this limit?**

Comment: This is just pedantic tag commentary (leave the tag, it is ultimately more useful than it is wrong), but Blast Boots are not a magic item!!!!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I know, I was looking for a "non-magical item" tag, but could not find any. Should we create one?

Comment: I don’t think so - while incorrect in terms of rules, it’s the right tag in terms of how someone looking for this sort of content might find it. Just a funny edge case that I couldn’t help but point out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## You are not limited by your Speed*

Reading the boots:

> you can increase the horizontal distance of your Long Jump by up to 45 feet.

I think you might be tripping up on the "up to" clause here - that clause makes it so that you aren't forced to Long Jump an additional 45 feet, but can instead only go, for example, 30 feet extra. Having a fixed distance increase would significantly weaken the item and make it unusable in a lot of situations.

I'm in favor of the most straightforward reading - the boots say you can go an additional 45 feet or less, so you can. There's no limitation by your Speed. The Blast Boots ability is the more specific case than the general rule of "you can't Leap further than your Speed", so Blast Boots wins. If the desginers wanted you to remain limited by your Speed, it's simple enough to say so. They do so for some abilities, like a Kobold's [Winglets](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2384). This aligns with the wording of Long Jump:

> Increase the **maximum** horizontal distance you Leap...

If you rolled to Long Jump at DC 30 and succeeded, you could still only go 20 feet if you wanted.

### (Technically you are still limited by your Speed)

With the Moderate Blast Boots, your maximum leaping distance (assuming you are succeeding at the Athletics check) becomes your Speed + 45 feet. So you are still technically limited by your Speed.

Answer (score 1):

### You are still limited by your speed, but have other benefits

The rules for movement say

> Your movement during encounter mode depends on the actions and other abilities you use. Whether you Stride, Step, Swim, or Climb, **the maximum distance you can move is based on your Speed**.

The boots do not say they remove the limit so they do not. The boots however do not only increase your jump distance. The core function of these boots is:

> When you Activate the blast boots, you can High Jump or Long Jump, **without the need to Stride first**.

So you still get value out of them. Normally to [long jump](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=37):

> You Stride, then make a horizontal Leap (...) If you didn’t Stride at least 10 feet, or if you attempt to jump in a different direction than your Stride, you automatically fail your check.

With the boots, you don't need to waste 10 feet of your Speed first, you can directly jump, and because you do not need to stride, in any direction. The moderate version of the boots also adds this second capability:

> When you Activate the moderate blast boots to High Jump, you can increase the vertical distance of your High Jump by up to 30 feet

This is within the movement of most characters. So unless you have a high movement or want to jump high, you should just buy the lesser version of the boots, which are considerably cheaper at 3 gp, compared to the 11 gp for moderate boots.